# How can I fix this Weird Wordpress Fatal Error?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, fatal-error

How can I fix

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home1/username/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/resto/inc/hooks/homepage-blog.php on line 196

I changed my wordpress site to the Resto theme and then got that error. Now I can't click "Add New" theme without that error popping up.

I managed to get a previous theme reinstalled by messing around but Can't change to a new theme now because of that error.

Comment: Please share the code block of the mentioned file.

Comment: What's your host PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the theme from Cpanel or via FTP. And try to activate an existing theme like `twentyseventeen`.

I got a video, you can activate a theme from Database. [Video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWR0x9GgRU4)

Or with `WP-CLI` you can install and activate theme with a command `wp theme install themeslug --activate`

for `Twenty Seventeen` theme slug is `twentyseventeen`